# SP 2013 - Audit Report - Custom Report - Filters not working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, auditing, reports

We have setup up SP 2013 and enabled auditing. The issue is when I try to run a custom report on a sub site I get the **error**...It does not allow me to select using browse buttons in either the "**Save location**" or the "**Restrict the report to**:" browse.

> **Sorry, something went wrong**
>
> **Report contains no data.**

I have included screenshot of what I am running. When I return to the screen after the error the "Restrict the report to" checkbox is unticked and the text field greyed out.

[image]

As a foot note I have also tried this directly from a custom list item (custom lists I need to get this working on). 
I click on **Compliance details** > **Generate audit log report** with the following errors:
***When I attempt to change the save location***

> Sorry, something went wrong   Reports cannot be stored at
>   '/Documents'. Reports can only be stored in a document library in the
>   current site.

***When I do not change the list save location***

> Sorry, something went wrong  Report contains no data.

Comment: I was able to resolve the above issue by selecting a document library as location and selecting a higher Date Range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be a site collection administrator, then you can do:

Site Actions

Site Settings

Modify All Site Settings

Site Collection Administration

Site collection audit settings

Cofigure Audit Settings - and check the boxes that are appropriate for your case.

This article help you to configure audit setting and view audit log reports from Site settings: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/126012-how-to-track-changes-on-sharepoint-server-2013

Thanks,

Comment: This does not solve my problem. As mentioned from the outset - auditing has been enabled. The issue still is unresolved